# Use map over a list of 50 generated colours to count, using filter, and reduce, or len, the frequency of occurence

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, reduce

> Given:
>
> ```
> c = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "orange", "white", "black"]
> ```
>
> Generate and print a list of 50 random colours. You will need to
>   use the `random` module to get `random` numbers.
>
> Use `range` and `map` to generate the
>   required amount of numbers.
>
> Then use `map` to translate numbers to colours.  Then use `map` over the colours to count (using `filter`, and `reduce` or `len`) how often
>   each colour occurs. Print the result.

This is what I've got so far:

```
import random
colours = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'purple', 'orange', 'white', 'black']
nums = map(lambda x: random.randint(0,7), range(50))
c = map(lambda y: colours[y], nums)
```

Which when printed, gives me the required set of 50 random colours from the given list. I'm sort of confused as to where to move from here.

Comment: Are you going to find out how often each colour occurs? You can just use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to do that by the way.

Comment: Looks like the homework doesn't allow it! :D

Comment: filter is used maybe like this for each color: len(filter(lambda x: x == color, c)) this will give you each of the color's count

Comment: Ugh. In real life, you could just do `random_colours = map(lambda x: random.choice(colours), range(50))` and get the randomly generated colours automatically, none of this 'get index first' nonsense...

Comment: I actually like the question, yes it's not the most common way of doing things, but it actually calls for knowledge of the built-in python functions

Comment: Yeah the point of this task is to get some knowledge behind the built-in python functions before we start moving on to list comprehension (I assume). Starting from the ground up, so to speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one also uses zip so you have a reference of the color being counted:

```
zip(colours, map(lambda x: len(filter(lambda y: y==x, c)), colours))
```

The way to use reduce to count the elements was giving me some thought, the only way I found of doing it was this:

```
map(lambda color: reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, map(lambda y: 1,filter(lambda x: x==color, c))), colours)
```